Salesforce REST API: eTag & Last-Modified headers
I am analyzing the behavior of Salesforce public rest API:
sObject describe API is supposed to return metadata about the entity (/services/data/{version}/sobjects/{entityName}/describe)
The response contains eTag and Last-Modified headers.
When I place a request, I am doing that on behalf of the user.
If I go and add a new custom field for the entity, for example, Account. The objectDescribe response is expected to change. As a result, the eTag and Last-Modified headers too.
Observation1: the payload doesn't change if the user does not have access to that new custom field. At the same time, the eTag and Last-Modified headers do change. It makes me think that while the object's describe representation changes, it doesn't factor in the user, it encompasses all possible states, a superset. Am I wright?
Observation2: there are times that the value of Last-Modified header "goes back in time". It chronologically precedes the value that was observed in prior requests.Is it some eventual consistency in action or my requests are hitting different application nodes?
Are values of Last-Modified and eTag supposed to change in tandem, in lock step with each other?
I need to understand this behavior better to build a reliable app. Any information on the topic will be valuable.

the payload doesn't change if the user does not have access to that new custom field. At the same time, the eTag and Last-Modified headers do change - seems like you've answered your own, unasked question.

What about child relationships? Same behaviour?

One more thing that I have noticed: the eTag + last-Modified changes, but the last-modified goes back in time

It'd be helpful if you describe your goals as an edit to your question. While these APIs emit ETag and Last-Modified, it's unlikely that these headers can be used as authoritative markers for determining if the schema has changed.  ETag allegedly works in the context of UI APIs and the UI APIs do have endpoints for retrieving object metadata.

For the "back in time" thing, I suspect you are right and you are observing a delay while syncing changes between servers in the instance your org runs on. How often are you seeing this, and for how long? Did you see the timestamp go "back in time" but the etag not do the equivalent? (I.e. did you ever see an old timestamp and new etag together?)
